# Stack walk with inline asm for VC++

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

I have inserted the following asm code in my C++ code. I am using a VC++ compiler.

```
char c;
curr_stack_return_addr = s.AddrFrame.Offset; //I am doing a stack walk
    __asm{  
            push bx
            mov eax, curr_stack_return_addr  
            mov bl, BYTE PTR [eax - 1]
            mov c,bl
            pop bx

     }
```

I get the correct value in c for my functions but it crashes when it reaches system functions on stack. I get no compiler errors. What did I do wrong?

**Resolved: I forgot to check for end of stack! The return address in last frame is 0. Thanks everyone.**

Comment: When does it crash ? How do you know you got correct value in c

Comment: Try removing the line, " mov bl, BYTE PTR [eax - 1]". I am not experienced with Assembly but I suspect you maybe addressing incorrect memory here. Your fix may revolve around this.

Comment: Please, do a stack walk with StackWalk64, unless you have multi-threading + performance critical considerations.

Comment: you don't need to `push bx`, and even if you did `push ebx` would be more efficient.  Unlike GNU C inline asm, MSVC inline asm saves any registers you use.  (see also [this comparison of GNU C inline asm vs. MSVC style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323445/what-is-the-difference-between-asm-and-asm/35959859#35959859).  Actually, I don't understand why you need inline asm for this at all.  I could see using it to get the current value of `esp` or something, but you could and should do this with pure C by casting to a pointer-to-struct or to `char*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two problems here:

1. `push bl` and `pop bl` don't exist. You can only push and pop word or dwords. The compiler warns by the way.
2. How do you know that eax points to a legal address?

Answer (score 3):

You have no way of knowing the value of eax when your program enters the asm block.

Comment: Indeed, `eax` is probably the most frequently clobbered register.

Comment: EAX contains an address in system dll. Do you think that is the reason?

Comment: @Bruce: from the posted code you can't know what eax points to. Can you post a more complete code?