# GAS assembly snippet divides by 0, not sure why

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, divide-by-zero, i386

I have the following function, involving a snippet of i386 assembly in GAS syntax:

```
inline int MulDivRound(
    int nNumber,
    int nNumerator,
    int nDenominator )
{
    int nRet, nMod;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "mov    %2,     %%eax   \n"
        "mull   %3              \n"
        "divl   %4              \n"
        "mov    %%eax,  %0      \n"
        "mov    %%edx,  %1      \n"

        :   "=m"    (nRet),
            "=m"    (nMod)
        :   "m"     (nNumber),
            "m"     (nNumerator),
            "m"     (nDenominator)
        :   "eax", "edx"
    );

    return nRet + nMod*2 / nDenominator;
}
```

I've noticed that, in a few instances, I'm getting an `EXC_I386_DIV` crash with this function. The following call produces such a crash:

```
int res = MulDivRound( 4096, -566, 400 );
```

I can't see clearly what is happening to cause this function to divide by 0: surely it just moves 4096 to `eax`, then multiplies that by -566, then divides that by 400, returning the two components of the result of the division operation. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger to see the register values before each instruction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

division / multiplication instructions in x86 ... there's a few things wrong in this code:

You're using signed operands with the *unsigned* `mul` / `div` operations. The operations that you *really* perform therefore are:

1. the signed `-566` (`0xfffffdca` as 2-complement 32bit) is interpreted as unsigned `4294958538`
2. this is multiplied by `4096` resulting in `17592183726080` (`0xfff:0xffdca000` in `EDX:EAX`). Notice the *lower* 32bit of that convert to `-2318336` as you "expect"
3. The full 64bit value is divided by `400` but due to the fact that the upper 32bit are `0xfff`, `4095`), the result exceeds `UINT32_MAX` and the exception is raised.

If you clear the upper 32bits by inserting an `xor %%edx,%%edx` before the `divl`, the operation will succeed but it'll return you something you don't expect - namely, it divides `0xffdca000` (`4292648960`) by `400` resulting in `0xa3c066` (`10731622`) in `EAX` and the remainder, `0xa0` (`160`) in `EDX`.

That's "correct" as far as what you instructed the machine to do, but not what you expect. If you want to use signed numbers, you need `imul` / `idiv` instead.

The assembly can ultimately be simplified into the following:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (
    "imull   %3              \n"
    "idivl   %4              \n"
    :   "=a"    (nRet),
        "=&d"   (nMod)
    :   "a"     (nNumber),
        "mr"    (nNumerator),
        "mr"    (nDenominator)
    :   "cc"
);
```

That's because gcc allows to specify which registers to use as input / output, so no data moves are necessary at all here. Also, the `"m"` constraint alone creates suboptimal code on 64bit as it forces the arguments onto the stack; give it an alternative and the generated code will be better.

**Edit:** just changed the `nMod` constraint to `"=&d"(nMod)`; it needs to be what gcc calls an "early clobber". This means that the specified output register is overwritten before all input operands are consumed/used, and tells the compiler not to pass inputs (the `(nDenominator)`, in particular) in `EDX`. Otherwise, were that to happen, it would cause an "interesting" failure mode. This is not an issue if you *only* use the `"m"` for `nNumerator`/`nDenominator` but once registers are allowed, one better be careful.

**Edit2:** Also note that the above code isn't proof against overflow exceptions of course. You can still call it like `MulDivRound(INT32_MAX, 4, 2)` to trigger those. Legitimately / by the way these instructions are designed. If you must make sure that doesn't happen, you've got to add code which compares the denominator against `EDX`/`RDX` before the `[i]div` and handle the case where it's smaller.

Comment: +1 Good solution with the "no data moves necessary" - just wanted to update my answer with some code, but this would have included a MOV from edx to eax :)

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks. The use of `"=a"` resp. `"=d"` (and/or the same for the inputs) with the `[i]mul`/`[i]div` opcodes on x86 is well-known, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10781271/512360 for another example. One thing to keep in mind about `[i]div` in particular is what you mentioned - in _most_ cases, you need to either clear `EDX`/`RDX` or sign-extend `EAX`/`RAX` into it (`CDQ`/`CQTO` instruction) before you call `[i]div`. Not necessary for this _specific_ case here as the `imul` has done the right thing already.

Answer (score 4):

You do not get a division by zero error, but an **overflow error**.

`divl` divides `rdx:rax / operand` (higher word in rdx) and stores the result in `eax` and the remainder in `edx`.

In your code you end up with `rdx=4095` and `rax=0`, so you try to divide `75539416981840613867520 / 400` which results in `188848542454601534668 remainder 320`.

`188848542454601534668` is `0x 000a 3ccc cccc cccc cccc` which does not fit in the 32 bit result register `eax`, hence the overflow error.

You need to make sure that `rax` contains your value `4095` and that `rdx=0`. This gives the proper result in rax (result) and rdx (remainder):

```
rax            0xa      10
rdx            0x5f     95
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Currently just before the divide instruction I've got `rax = 0x00000000ffdca000` and `rdx = 0x0000000000000fff`. What instructions would I use to get these values into the correct registers for the divide instruction?