# What is the best way to perform a division and a modulo for the processor?

Tags: c++, c, division, modulo, processor

How to perform a division **AND** a modulo at the same time. Is it possible for the processor ?

Like :

```
int a, b = 8 / 3; //a = 2, b = 2
```

Or is there an operation which is better than :

```
int a = 8 / 3;
int b = 8 % 3;
```

Maybe this is better ?

```
int a = 8 / 3;
int b = 8 - a * 3;
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608559/division-and-modulus-using-single-divl-instruction-i386-amd64 might be of interest.

Comment: Your optimizing compiler should know better than you, so don't bother (and I guess it does not matter that much in practice: cache misses cost much more than divisions)

Comment: It's possible for the processor if it has an instruction that does it. There are many different processors, all with different capabilities. The 6502 doesn't even have division (or multiplication, for that matter).

Comment: @molbdnilo There is a C++ compiler for the 6502?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: I am not sure all compilers can apply this trick. For compute-intensive code, it really matters to try and avoid divisions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Divide and Get Remainder at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895081/divide-and-get-remainder-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following function:

```
std::pair<int, int> divmod(int x, int y)
{
    return { x / y, x % y };
}
```

Compiling this with `g++ -std=c++11 -O1 -S` spits out the following assembly code:

```
movl    %edi, %eax
cltd
idivl   %esi
salq    $32, %rdx
movl    %eax, %eax
orq     %rdx, %rax
ret
```

As you can see, it only contains a single division on line 3. Optimizers are very good at this stuff.

Comment: Great stuff! Moreoever, a compiler will also replace `% y` -> `& (y-1)` and `/ y` with `<< log2(y)` if `y` is a power of two. No need to worry about such micro-optimizations and just write the most expressive code.

Answer (score 5):

> Maybe this is better?

Why would it be? It’s obscure, both to the programmer and the compiler/optimiser. Without having looked at the compiler output, I’d imagine that any decent optimiser sees your first code and says “ah, a div and a mod being performed, I’d better emit the `divmod`<sup>1</sup> opcode”. Whereas in the second case the optimiser is well within its right to shrug and leave it at that.

As a general rule (with many exceptions though), the cleanest code which has its semantics stated directly is also the code that is easiest to optimise.

---

<sup>1</sup> For a given processor, the opcode name may differ.

Comment: +1. The most common optimizers are peephole optimizers, because they're so simple. That's just a set of rules in the form "If you see pattern `XYZ`, replace by instructions sequence `AB`". In particular, there's a finite set of common patterns `XYZ`. `a/b,a%b` is a common pattern, `a/b, a - (a/b)*b` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are creating a solution to a problem that `<cstdlib>`'s `std::div` is provided to solve?

```
namespace std
{

struct div_t
{
    int quot;
    int rem;
};
struct ldiv_t
{
    long int quot;
    long int rem;
};
struct lldiv_t
{
    long long int quot;
    long long int rem;
};

  div_t div ( int numer, int denom );
 ldiv_t div ( long int numer, long int denom );
lldiv_t div ( long long int numer, long long int denom );

}; // namespace std
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/div/