# whatis similar to RotateToLeft in c#?

Tags: c#, java

in java there is a function called rotatetoleft that generate a nunmber generated

```java
int n;
n = Integer.rotateLeft(1, 5);
System.out.print(n);
```

output; 32

what is similar to this in c# ?

Comment: Please note that the `<<` and `>>` operators do the same job in Java dn C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're just after the `<<` operator, but that *only* performs a left-shift; it won't rotate into the LSB. To do that, you'd have to do a mixture of shifts and ORs. For example:

```
static int RotateLeft(int value, int shift)
{
    return (value << shift) | (value >> (32 - shift));
}
```

Note that this won't quite work properly if `value` has its top bit set due to sign extension on the shift right. You can fix that by doing the arithmetic in `uint`:

```
static int RotateLeft(int value, int shift)
{
    unchecked
    {
        uint uvalue = (uint) value;
        uint uresult = (uvalue << shift) | (uvalue >> 32 - shift);
        return (int) uresult;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's also fun (imo) is that you can skip the 32's, like `(uvalue << shift) | (uvalue >> -shift)`, because that 32 only affects the bits that are ignored anyway.

Comment: @harold: Yes, I considered that - but felt the 32 part was clearer.

Comment: @JonSkeet hah thanks ! 599k of reputation ! can u please just give me quick comment on substring in java the index can be higher then lenght but in c# how can i do that?

Comment: @studentofmp: That's an unrelated question - and I don't believe it's true anyway (it'll throw an exception). Ask a new question once you've validated your main point.

Comment: @JonSkeet i have done it and here my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536161/whatis-similar-to-substring-of-java-if-index-is-higher-then-string-in-c

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's something like that in C#, I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134805/bitwise-rotate-left-function) and an answer suggests this implementation: (C language)

```
unsigned int _rotl(const unsigned int value, int shift) 
{
    if ((shift &= sizeof(value) * 8 - 1) == 0)
      return value;
    return (value << shift) | (value >> (sizeof(value)*8 - shift));
}

unsigned int _rotr(const unsigned int value, int shift) 
{
    if ((shift &= sizeof(value) * 8 - 1) == 0)
      return value;
    return (value >> shift) | (value << (sizeof(value)*8 - shift));
}
```