# whatis similar to Substring of java if index is higher then string in c#?

Tags: c#, java

in java the substring function(index,lenght) the index can be higher then lenght

```
System.out.print("BCDABCD".substring(3 , 7));
```

this output "ABCD"

i dont want this

```
Console.Writeline("BCDABCD".substring(3 , 4));
```

for ex if i want to generate this :

```
for i = 0 to 63 {Console.Writeline("BCDABCD".substring(i , i + 1 )));
```

how to do that in c# ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter of [`String.substring(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) in Java isn't the *length* - it's the (exclusive) upper bound of the index. Whereas in .NET, the second parameter of [`String.Substring(int, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) really *is* a length.

So any time you call `foo.substring(x, y)` in Java, that's equivalent to `foo.Substring(x, y - x)` in .NET... and you really need to take that into account.

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but your loop wouldn't work in Java either. If you really want to just get a single character from the string, just use the indexer along with `%`:

```
string text = "BCDABCD";
for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text[i % text.Length]);
}
```

EDIT: Given the comment, I suspect you just want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("BCDABCD".Substring(3 - (j & 3), 4));
}
```

... in other words, the length will always be 4.

Comment: in java here is my function    for (int j = 0; j < 64;j++) 

{
"BCDABCD".substring(3 - (j & 3), 7 - (j & 3))}
how to do that with the answer solution ?

Comment: @studentofmp: See my edited answer. (It would have helped if you'd told us what output you actually want...)

Comment: in java my code works it generates : 

ABCD
DABC
CDAB
BCDA

X

Comment: @studentofmp: Right. You should get the same output from my code (second snippet).