# Bit Manipulations - rotateLeft

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

The goal is to write a method that moves n number of bits in a 32 bit machine to the left by only using ~, !, |, &, ^, +, >>, << (no for loops, if statements, so on...). I think that what I've got should work. My problem is that the variable move_left seems to not behave properly. Here is my code which is broken down into steps in order for me to track down the problem:

```
int rotateLeft(int x, int n) 
 {
     int move_left = (0x20 + (~n + 1)); // 32 - n
     int expr1 = x >> n; // chopping off n bits on the right
     int expr2 = ~((~0x0) << n); // n number of 1s on the right
     int expr3 = expr2 & x; // the bits that now need to be on the left
     int expr4 = expr3 << move_left; // the correct bits on the left
     int expr7 = ~0x0 << move_left; // breaking down expr5
     int expr5 = (~((~0x0) << move_left)); //
     int expr6 = expr5 & expr1; // copying the right sided body
     int result = expr6 | expr4; //adding the left side

     printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", move_left, expr1, expr7, expr5, expr6, expr4);

     return result;
 }
```

When testing with rotateLeft(-2147483648[0x80000000],0[0x0]) the result, however, is incorrect. When tracking down my arguments, the print is:

```
32
-2147483648
-1
0
0
0
```

I do not understand how move_left is 32 (which is right), but ~0x0 << move_left is somehow -1 when it should be 0! (When I substitute left_right with 0x20 in expr7, then it prints 0 correctly.)

I appreciate any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bitwise rotate left function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134805/bitwise-rotate-left-function)

Comment: Why are you allowed to use `~`? It's not on your list of permissible operations.

Comment: EOF, we are allowed to use it! Whoops, will add it to my question.

Comment: How about `return x << n;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C99 standard, clause 6.5.7 (3), on bitshift operators:

> (...) If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, **the behavior is undefined.**

As you have experienced, this is not a purely theoretical concern; there are platforms on which bitshift operations with operands outside this range do any number of things because it was easier/faster/more efficient/required less space to build the hardware that way. But it doesn't end there. Quoth  6.5.7(4):

> The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeroes. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1` x 2<sup>`E2`</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If `E1` has signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1` x 2<sup>`E2`</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

and (5):

> The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type or if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of `E1` / 2<sup>`E2`</sup>. **If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.**

Often a signed left shift beyond the defined range will behave predictably, and there will often be sign-extension on a signed right shift (meaning that ones are shifted in for negative values and zeroes for positive ones), but you can't depend on that.

Long story short: **If you're trying to use bitshifts with signed integer types, you're gonna have a bad time.** Use `unsigned int` for everything, including literals on the left side of a shift (for example, use `~0u` instead of `0`) and take care that your right-hand side operands remain in the legal range.

So how do you do the last bit without `if` and `?:`? One way is to split the shift:

```
 unsigned int expr1 = (x >> (n & 0xf)) >> (n & 0x10);
 unsigned int expr2 = ~((~0u << (n & 0xf)) << (n & 0x10));
```

This works because `(n & 0xf) + (n & 0x10) == (n & 0x1f)` and `((x >> a) >> b) == (x >> (a + b))`. I'm assuming unsigned `x` here, otherwise you need a cast.

I can think of simpler ways to do leftwise rotation, but, well, it's your homework.

Comment: thank you, sir! I am not allowed to use unsigned but at least I now understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really complicated for task of left rotation.
What I see in your code, that can be a problem, is a data type.
When signed int is shided rignt sign bit is coppying, e.g. the foolowing code

```cpp
    int x = 0x80000000;
    x >>=3;
    printf("%X\n", x);
```

prints result:

```
    F0000000
```

But if data type is changed to unsigned:

```cpp
    unsigned int x = 0x80000000;
    x >>=3;
    printf("%X\n", x);
```

result will be:

```
    10000000
```

So, try to output in hexadecimal to see what happened, and then try to use unsigned type to change bitwise operations logic.