# Understanding PowerPC rlwinm instruction

Tags: c, powerpc

So I finally convinced myself to try and learn/use PowerPC (PPC).
Everything is going well and most information was found online.
However, when looking at some examples I came across this:

```
rlwinm    r3, r3, 0,1,1
```

How would I do this in C?
I tried doing some research, but couldn't find anything that helped me out.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

`rlwinm` stands for "Rotate Left Word Immediate then aNd with Mask, and it's correct usage is

```
rlwinm  RA, RS, SH, MB, ME
```

As per the [description page](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.alangref/idalangref_rlwinm_rlinm_rtlwrdimm_instrs.htm):

> - RA  Specifies target general-purpose register where result of operation is stored.
> - RS  Specifies source general-purpose register for operation.
> - SH  Specifies shift value for operation.
> - MB  Specifies begin value of mask for operation.
> - ME  Specifies end value of mask for operation.
> - BM  Specifies value of 32-bit mask.

And

> - If the MB value is less than the ME value + 1, then the mask bits
>     between and including the starting point and the end point are set to
>     ones. All other bits are set to zeros.
> - If the MB value is the same as
>     the ME value + 1, then all 32 mask bits are set to ones.
> - If the MB value is greater than the ME value + 1, then all of the mask bits
>     between and including the ME value +1 and the MB value -1 are set to
>     zeros. All other bits are set to ones.

So in your example the source and target are the same. Shift amount is `0`, so no shift. And `MB=ME=1`, so the first case applies, such that the mask becomes all zeros with bit number 1 as `1`, while numbering from `MSB=0`: `0x40000000`.

In C we can write it as simple as

```
a &= 0x40000000;
```

assuming `a` is 32-bit variable.

Answer (score 2):

`rlwinm` rotates the value of a register left by the specified number, performs an `AND` and stores the result in a register.

Example: `rlwinm r3, r4, 5, 0, 31`

`r4` is the source register which is rotated by `5` and before the rotated result is placed in `r3`, it is also `AND`ed with a bit mask of only 1s since the interval between `0` and `31` is the entire 32-bit value.

Example taken from [here](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Assembler_Tutorial).

For a `C` implementation you may want to take a look at [how to rotate left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134805/bitwise-rotate-left-function) and [how to `AND`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_assignment_operators) which should be trivial to build together now. Something like the following should work:

```
int rotateLeft(int input, int shift) {
    return (input << shift) | ((input >> (32 - shift)) & ~(-1 << shift));
}

int rlwinm(int input, int shift, int mask) {
    return rotateLeft(input, shift) & mask;
}
```

Comment: Note that PowerPC counts bits from the left, with MSB = bit 0.  (Many other ISAs, like x86, count bits from the right).