# Indexed addressing mode and implied addressing mode

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, risc

Indexed addressing mode is usually used for accessing arrays as arrays are stored contiguosly. We have a index register which gets incremented in every iteration which when added to base address gives the array element address.
I don't understand the actual need of this addressing mode. Why can't we do this with direct addressing ? We have the base address and we can just add 1 to it every time when accessing. Why do we need indexed addressing mode which has a overhead of index register ?

I am not sure about the instruction format for implied addressing mode. Suppose we have a instruction INC AC. Is the address of AC specified in the instruction or is there a special opcode which means 'INC AC'  and we don't include the address of AC (accumulator)?

Comment: Do you mean `AX`?  x86 doesn't have an AC register.

Comment: @PeterCordes Maybe I should remove x86 tag. But you can answer considering AX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand the actual need of this addressing mode.   Why can't we do this with direct addressing?

You can; MIPS only has one addressing mode and compilers can still generate code for it just fine.  But sometimes it has to use an extra shift + `add` instruction to calculate an address (if it's not just looping through an array).

The point of addressing modes is to save instructions and save registers, especially in 2-operand instruction sets like x86, where `add eax, ecx` overwrites `eax` with the result (`eax += ecx`), unlike MIPS or other 3-instruction ISAs where `addu $t2, $t1, $t0` does `t2 = t1 + t0`.  On x86, that would require a copy (`mov`) and an `add`.  (Or in that special case, `lea edx, [eax+ecx]`: x86 can copy-and-add (and shift) using the same instruction-encoding it uses for memory operands.)

Consider a histogram problem: you generate array indices in unpredictable order, and have to index an array.  On x86-64, `add dword [rbx + rdi*4], 1` will increment a 32-bit counter in memory using a single 4-byte instruction, which decodes to only 2 uops for the front-end to issue into the out-of-order core on modern Intel CPUs.  (http://agner.org/optimize/).  (`rbx` is the base register, `rdi` is a scaled index).  Having a *scaled* index is very powerful; x86 16-bit addressing modes support 2 registers, but not a scaled index.

Classic MIPS only has separate shift and add instructions, although MIPS32 did add a scaled-add instruction for address calculation.  That would save an instruction here.  Being a load-store machine, the loads and stores always have to be separate instructions (unlike on x86 where that add decodes as a micro-fused load+add and a store.  See [INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510095/inc-instruction-vs-add-1-does-it-matter)).

Probably ARM would be a better comparison for MIPS: It's also a load-store RISC machine.  But it does have a selection of addressing modes, including scaled index using the barrel shifter.  So instead of needing a separate shift / add for each array index, you'd use [`LDR   R0, [R1, R2, LSL #2]`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABCAEDD.html), `add r0, r0, #1` / `str` with the same addressing mode.

Often when looping through an array, it is best to just increment pointers on x86.  But it's also an option to use an index, especially for loops with multiple arrays using the same index, like `C[i] = A[i] + B[i]`.  Indexed addressing mode can sometimes be [slightly less efficient in hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes), though, so when a compiler is unrolling a loop it usually should use pointers, even though it has to increment all 3 pointers separately instead of one index.

---

The point of instruction-set design is not merely to be Turing complete, it's to enable *efficient* code that gets more work done with fewer clock cycles and/or smaller code-size, or give programmers the option of aiming for either of those goals.

The minimum threshold for a computer to be programmable is extremely low, see for example various [One instruction set computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer) architectures.  (None implemented for real, just designed on paper to show that it's possible to write programs with nothing but a subtract-and-branch-if-less-than-zero instruction, with memory operands encoded in the instruction.

There's a tradeoff between easy to decode (especially to decode in parallel) vs. compact.  x86 is horrible because it evolved as a series of extensions, often without a lot of planning to leave room for future extensions.  If you're interested in ISA design decisions, have a look at Agner Fog's blog for interesting discussion about designing an ISA for high-performance CPUs that combines the best of x86 (lots of work with one instruction, e.g. memory operand as part of an ALU instruction) with the best features of RISC (easy to decode, lots of registers): [Proposal for an ideal extensible instruction set](http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=421).

There's also a tradeoff in how you spend the bits in an instruction word, especially in a fixed instruction width ISA like most RISCs.  Different ISAs made different choices.

- PowerPC uses lots of the coding space for powerful bitfield instructions like [`rlwinm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896622/understanding-powerpc-rlwinm-instruction) (rotate left and mask off a window of bits), and lots of opcodes.  IDK if the generally unpronounceable and hard-to-remember mnemonics are related to that...
- ARM uses the high 4 bits for predicated execution of any instruction based on condition codes.  It uses more bits for [the barrel shifter](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/barrel-shifter.html) (the 2nd source operand is optionally shifted or rotated by an immediate or a count from another register).
- MIPS has relatively large immediate operands, and is basically simple.

x86 32/64-bit addressing modes use a variable-length encoding, with an extra byte SIB (scale/index/base) byte when there's an index, and an optional disp8 or disp32 immediate displacement.  (e.g. `add esi, [rax + rdx + 12340]` takes 2 + 1 + 4 bytes to encode, vs. 2 bytes for `add esi, [rax]`.

x86 16-bit addressing modes are much more limited, and pack everything except the optional disp8/disp16 displacement into the ModR/M byte.

---

> Suppose we have a instruction INC AC. Is the address of AC specified in the instruction or is there a special opcode which means 'INC AC' and we don't include the address of AC (accumulator)?

Yes, the machine-code format for some instructions in some ISAs includes implicit operands.  Many machines have `push` / `pop` instructions that implicitly use a specific register as the stack pointer.  For example, in x86-64's `push rax`, RAX is an explicit register operand ([encoded in the low 3 bits of the one-byte opcode using the `push r64` short form](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/PUSH)), while RSP is an implicit operand.

Older 8-bit CPUs often had instructions like DECA (to decrement the accumulator, A).  i.e. there was a specific opcode for that register.  This could be the same thing as having a DEC instruction with some bits in the opcode byte specifying which register (like x86 does before x86-64 repurposed the [short INC/DEC encodings](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/DEC) as REX prefixes: note the "N.E" (Not Encodeable) in the 64-bit mode column for `dec r32`).  But if there's no regular pattern then it can definitely be considered an implicit operand.

Sometimes putting things into neat categories breaks down, so don't worry too much about whether using bits with the opcode byte counts as implicit or explicit for x86.  It's a way of spending more opcode space to save code-size for commonly used instructions while still allowing use with different registers.

Some ISAs only use a certain register as the stack pointer by convention, with no implicit uses.  MIPS is like this.

ARM32 (in ARM, not Thumb mode) also uses explicit operands in push/pop.  Its push/pop mnemonics are just aliases for store-multiple decrement-before / load-multiple increment-after (LDMIA / STMDB) to implement a full-descending stack.  See [ARM's docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABCAEDD.html) for LDM/STM which explains this, and what you can do with the general case of these instructions, e.g. LDMDB to decrement a pointer and then load (in the opposite direction of POP).

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborate answer.