# Generating CMOV instructions using Microsoft compilers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, x86, disassembly

In an effort to eke out some cmov instructions on an intel core 2 running windows 7 pro I wrote the code below. All it does is take a string from the console as input, apply some shift operations to generate a random seed, and then pass that seed on to srand, for the generation of a small array of pseudorandom numbers. The pseudorandom numbers are then evaluated for whether they satisfy the predicate function ( more arbitrary bitshuffling ), and output a '*' or a '_'. The purpose of the experiment is to generate cmov instructions, but as you can see in the disassembly below, there are none.

Any tips on how to change the code or the cflags so that they'll be generated?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

bool blackBoxPredicate( const unsigned int& ubref ) {
   return ((ubref << 6) ^ (ubref >> 2) ^ (~ubref << 2)) % 15 == 0;
}

int main() {
   const unsigned int NUM_RINTS = 32;
   unsigned int randomSeed = 1;
   unsigned int popCount = 0;
   unsigned int * rintArray = new unsigned int[NUM_RINTS];
   std::string userString;

   std::cout << "input a string to use as a random seed: ";
   std::cin >> userString;

   std::for_each( 
      userString.begin(), 
      userString.end(), 
      [&randomSeed] (char c) {
         randomSeed = (randomSeed * c) ^ (randomSeed << (c % 7));
   });

   std::cout << "seed computed: " << randomSeed << std::endl;

   srand(randomSeed);

   for( int i = 0; i < NUM_RINTS; ++i ) {
      rintArray[i] = static_cast<unsigned int> (rand());
      bool pr = blackBoxPredicate(rintArray[i]);
      popCount = (pr) ? (popCount+1) : (popCount);

      std::cout << ((pr) ? ('*') : ('_')) << " ";
   }

   std::cout << std::endl;

   delete rintArray;
   return 0;
}
```

And used this makefile to build it:

```
OUT=cmov_test.exe
ASM_OUT=cmov_test.asm
OBJ_OUT=cmov_test.obj
SRC=cmov_test.cpp
THIS=makefile

CXXFLAGS=/nologo /EHsc /arch:SSE2 /Ox /W3

$(OUT): $(SRC) $(THIS)
   cl $(SRC) $(CXXFLAGS) /FAscu /Fo$(OBJ_OUT) /Fa$(ASM_OUT) /Fe$(OUT)

clean:
   erase $(OUT) $(ASM_OUT) $(OBJ_OUT)
```

And yet when I went to see whether any had been generated, I saw that microsoft's compilers had generated the following assembly for that last for loop:

```
; 34   :       popCount = (pr) ? (popCount+1) : (popCount);
; 35   :       
; 36   :       std::cout << ((pr) ? ('*') : ('_')) << " ";

  00145 68 00 00 00 00   push    OFFSET $SG30347
  0014a 85 d2        test    edx, edx
  0014c 0f 94 c0     sete    al
  0014f f6 d8        neg     al
  00151 1a c0        sbb     al, al
  00153 24 cb        and     al, -53            ; ffffffcbH
  00155 04 5f        add     al, 95         ; 0000005fH
  00157 0f b6 d0     movzx   edx, al
  0015a 52       push    edx
  0015b 68 00 00 00 00   push    OFFSET ?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::cout
  00160 e8 00 00 00 00   call    ??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@D@Z ; std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >
  00165 83 c4 08     add     esp, 8
  00168 50       push    eax
  00169 e8 00 00 00 00   call    ??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z ; std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >
  0016e 46       inc     esi
  0016f 83 c4 08     add     esp, 8
  00172 83 fe 20     cmp     esi, 32            ; 00000020H
  00175 72 a9        jb  SHORT $LL3@main
```

For your reference, here are my cpu id strings and compiler version.

```
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=3a09

Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
```

Comment: If you want particular instructions, don't try to get the compiler to infer them as what it will do is subject to change with version, optimization settings, flags, etc.  Instead, use whatever inline assembly capability applies to that compiler, or link a genuine assembly language source file into the result.

Comment: under what conditions do optimizing c++ compilers normally generate cmov instructions? this is more of an experiment than for production use; I'd like to know how to write c++ that is easy for compilers to optimize for increasing branch prediction performance.

Comment: It used to be that `cmov` was slower than `cmp`+`jmp` if the branch was highly predictable, so compilers would be right to not use it often. Also, `cmov` created dependencies that cause it to run slower in a tight loop. I'm not sure if this is still the case. Maybe using PGO would encourage the compiler to do so by helping find mis-predicted branches?

Comment: write your dll in asssembler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It is *extremely* difficult, if not downright impossible, to get Microsoft's 32-bit C/C++ compiler to emit `CMOVcc` instructions.**

What you have to remember is that conditional moves were first introduced with the Pentium Pro processor, and while Microsoft had a compiler switch that would *tune* the generated code for this 6th generation processor (the long-deprecated [`/G6`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h66s5s0e(v=vs.71).aspx)), they never emitted code that would run *exclusively* on this processor. The code still needed to run on 5th generation processors (*i.e.*, Pentium and AMD K6), so it couldn't use `CMOVcc` instructions because those would have generated illegal instruction exceptions. Unlike Intel's compiler, global dynamic dispatching was not (and is still not) implemented.

Also, it is worth noting that no switch was ever introduced to target *exclusively* 6th generation processors and later. There's no `/arch:CMOV` or whatever they might call it. Supported values for the [`/arch` switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd.aspx) go straight from `IA32` (the lowest common denominator, for which `CMOV` would be potentially illegal) to `SSE`. However, [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd.aspx) *does* confirm that, as one might expect, enabling SSE or SSE2 code generation implicitly enables the use of conditional-move instructions and anything else that was introduced *before* SSE:

> In addition to using the SSE and SSE2 instructions, the compiler also uses other instructions that are present on the processor revisions that support SSE and SSE2. An example is the CMOV instruction that first appeared on the Pentium Pro revision of the Intel processors.

Therefore, in order to have any hope of getting the compiler to emit `CMOV` instructions, you must set `/arch:SSE` or higher. Nowadays, of course, this is no big deal. You can simply set `/arch:SSE` or `/arch:SSE2` and be safe, since all modern processors support these instruction sets.

But that's only half of the battle. Even when you have the right compiler switches enabled, it is extremely difficult to get MSVC to emit `CMOV` instructions. Here are two important observations:

1. **MSVC 10 (Visual Studio 2010) and earlier virtually *never* generate `CMOV` instructions.** I've *never* seen them in the output, no matter how many variations of source code I've tried. I say "virtually" because there might be some crazy edge case that I missed, but I very much doubt it. None of the optimization flags have any effect on this.

   **However, MSVC 11 (Visual Studio 2012) introduced significant improvements to the code generator**, at least in this aspect. This and later versions of the compiler now seem to be at least *aware* of the existence of the `CMOVcc` instructions, and *may* emit them under the right conditions (*i.e.*, `/arch:SSE` or later, and use of the conditional operator, as described below).
2. I've found that **the most effective way to cajole the compiler into emitting a `CMOV` instruction is to use the *conditional operator*** instead of a long-form `if`-`else` statement. Although these two constructs should be completely equivalent as far as the code generator is concerned, they are not.

   In other words, while you *might* see the following translated to a branchless `CMOVLE` instruction:

   ```
   int value = (a < b) ? a : b;
   ```

   you will *always* get branching code for the following sequence:

   ```
   int value;
   if (a < b)    value = a;
   else          value = b;
   ```

   At the very least, even if your use of the conditional operator doesn't cause a `CMOV` instruction (such as on MSVC 10 or earlier), you might still be lucky enough to get branchless code by some other means—*e.g.*, `SETcc` or clever use of `SBB` and `NEG`/`NOT`/`INC`/`DEC`. This is what the disassembly you've shown in the question uses, and although it is not quite as optimal as `CMOVcc`, it's certainly *comparable* and the difference is not worth worrying about. (The only other branching instruction is part of the loop.)

---

If you truly want branchless code (which [you often do when hand-optimizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991778/an-expensive-jump-with-gcc-5-4-0/40993519#40993519)), and you're not having any luck getting the compiler to generate the code you want, you'll need to get more clever in how you write the source code. I've had good luck with writing code that computes the result branchlessly using bitwise or arithmetic operators.

For example, you might wish that the following function generated optimal code:

```
int Minimum(int a, int b)
{
    return (a < b) ? a : b;
}
```

You followed rule #2 and used a conditional operator, but if you're using an older version of the compiler, you'll get branching code anyway. Outsmart the compiler using the classic trick:

```
int Minimum_Optimized(int a, int b)
{
    return (b + ((a - b) & -(a < b)));
}
```

The resulting object code is not perfectly optimal (it contains a `CMP` instruction that is redundant since `SUB` already sets the flags), but it is branchless and will therefore still be significantly faster than the original attempt on random inputs that cause branch prediction to fail.

As another example, imagine that you want to determine whether a 64-bit integer is negative in a 32-bit application. You write the following self-evident code:

```
bool IsNegative(int64_t value)
{
    return (value < 0);
}
```

and will find yourself sorely disappointed in the results. GCC and Clang optimize this sensibly, but MSVC spits out a nasty conditional branch. The (non-portable) trick is realizing that the sign bit is in the upper 32 bits, so you can isolate and test that explicitly using bitwise manipulation:

```
bool IsNegative_Optimized(int64_t value)
{
    return (static_cast<int32_t>((value & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000ULL) >> 32) < 0);
}
```

In addition, one of the commentators suggests using inline assembly. While this is possible (Microsoft's 32-bit compiler supports inline assembly), [it is often a poor choice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35959859/366904). Inline assembly disrupts the optimizer in rather significant ways, so unless you're writing *significant* swaths of code in inline assembly, there is unlikely to be a substantial net performance gain. Furthermore, Microsoft's inline assembly syntax is extremely limited. It trades flexibility for simplicity in a big way. In particular, there is no way to specify *input* values, so you're stuck loading the input from memory into a register, and the caller is forced to spill the input from a register to memory in preparation. This creates a phenomenon I like to call "a whole lotta shufflin' goin' on", or for short, "slow code". You don't drop to inline assembly in cases where slow code is acceptable. Thus, it is always preferable (at least on MSVC) to figure out how to write C/C++ source code that persuades the compiler to emit the object code you want. Even if you can only get *close* to the ideal output, that's still considerably better than the penalty you pay for using inline assembly.

---

Note that none of these contortions are necessary if you target x86-64. **Microsoft's 64-bit C/C++ compiler is significantly more aggressive about using `CMOVcc` instructions whenever possible**, even the older versions. As [this blog post explains](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2009/11/02/visual-c-code-generation-in-visual-studio-2010/), the x64 compiler bundled with Visual Studio 2010 contains a number of code-quality improvements, including better identification and use of `CMOV` instructions.

No special compiler flags or other considerations are necessary here, since *all* processors that support 64-bit mode support conditional moves. I suppose this is why they were able to get it right for the 64-bit compiler. I also suspect that some of these changes made to the x86-64 compiler in VS 2010 were ported to the x86-32 compiler in VS 2012, explaining why it is at least aware of the existence of `CMOV`, but it still doesn't use it as aggressively as the 64-bit compiler.

The bottom line is, when targeting x86-64, write the code in the way that makes the most sense. The optimizer actually knows how to do its job!

Comment: `(b + ((a - b) & -(a < b)))` also potentially has undefined behaviour if `a-b` overflows.  Some modern compilers might then make the assumption that `a-b` can't overflow when optimizing later code.  If `a` or `b` are constant (after inlining and constant-propgation), this turns into a simple range-limit that could result in an `if (a > 123456)` being optimized away as always false or always true.  In practice, I don't think it will usually be a problem, but modern C++ is unfortunately very far away from being a portable assembly language for targets with sane 2's complement signed integers.

Comment: Re: inline asm: I [wrote a whole answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323445/what-is-the-difference-between-asm-and-asm/35959859#35959859) about how bad MSVC-style inline asm is for wrapping single instructions, compared to GNU C syntax (but even then, https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).  You might want to link it.  BTW, I've never been clear on how it can work for MSVC inline asm to just leave a value in EAX and omit the `return` in a non-void function. Does this disable inlining of the function? Or does MSVC support this idiom when inlining to avoid a store/reload for results?

Comment: Sure, it potentially has undefined behavior, @Peter. None of this is portable. I've verified that it works correctly on MSVC. It is not one of those Gnu-style compilers that is indistinguishable from an adversary. :-) It might not be the best example, but it is code that I actually use when building for 32-bit on MSVC 2010. I frequently wish there was an actual portable assembly language, but neither C nor C++ are that language. MSVC's inline asm was primarily designed for "escapes", like executing DOS interrupts, back in the day. It wasn't designed for speed, and wasn't extended like GAS.

Comment: Leaving a value in EAX (or EDX:EAX) at the end of an inline asm block is perfectly legal and valid in MSVC. I think older versions of the compiler (we're talking pre-MSVC 6.0, a very long time ago now) used to issue a warning when you did this, something about execution falls off the end of the function without a return value, but the code generated was still correct in that case. The fact that the warning's been removed suggests to me that this is an explicitly supported idiom. The result never gets stored/reloaded if you write the code correctly. And no, it doesn't disable inlining.

Comment: Surprisingly, inlining works very well with functions that contain inline asm blocks, *unless* you try to force the function to use the `__fastcall` convention. Then it doesn't get inlined. (`__cdecl` and `__stdcall` both inline fine). This is pretty disappointing, because `__fastcall` would allow the first two parameters to be passed in registers, which would allow you to avoid paying at least some of the load/store penalties for reading parameters. Alas, it is not to be. I've played with tons of different ways of writing the code, and there's just no way around shuffling for the inputs.

Comment: I think Rust has the potential to be useful as a portable assembly language, but last I heard it didn't really have SIMD support :(  Not down to the choice of branching vs. branchless, but for integer stuff if you want popcnt you just write [`var.count_ones()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.count_ones), which is a built-in operation for primitive types.  Not like C where the portable option is to write a stupid loop and hope the compiler recognizes the idiom.  There's also saturating, and wrapping vs. checked add/sub/mul/whatever operations, rotates, etc.

Comment: What a piece of an answer. Must've taken several hours of investigation to uncover all these findings. Thanks a lot for sharing this, Cody.

Comment: Do you know of any way to get the x64 compiler to *not* emit CMOV in a tight loop?

Comment: @user541686 Possibly... Subtly changing the code should do it. Do you have a repro case? Maybe you should ask a new question about it. Ping me about it here if you do so.

Comment: I did at some point... it's been some time since I came across this. I do remember massaging it and finding it practically impossible in some particular cases (other cases were easier). I'll ping you if I manage to dig it up.