# Avoiding Conditional Statements in Loops

Tags: performance, fortran, nested-loops, intel-fortran

There is a portion of my f90 program that is taking up a significant amount of compute time. I am basically looping through three matrices (of the same size, with dimensions as large as 250-by-250), and trying to make sure values stay bounded within the interval [-1.0, 1.0]. I know that it is best practice to avoid conditionals in loops, but I am having trouble figuring out how to re-write this block of code for optimal performance. Is there a way to "unravel" the loop or use a built-in function of some sort to "vectorize" the conditional statements?

```
do ind2 = 1, size(u_mat,2)
    do ind1 = 1,size(u_mat,1)
        ! Dot product 1 must be bounded between [-1,1]
        if (b1_dotProd(ind1,ind2) .GT. 1.0_dp) then
            b1_dotProd(ind1,ind2) = 1.0_dp
        else if (b1_dotProd(ind1,ind2) .LT. -1.0_dp) then
            b1_dotProd(ind1,ind2) = -1.0_dp
        end if
        ! Dot product 2 must be bounded between [-1,1]
        if (b2_dotProd(ind1,ind2) .GT. 1.0_dp) then
            b2_dotProd(ind1,ind2) = 1.0_dp
        else if (b2_dotProd(ind1,ind2) .LT. -1.0_dp) then
            b2_dotProd(ind1,ind2) = -1.0_dp
        end if
        ! Dot product 3 must be bounded between [-1,1]
        if (b3_dotProd(ind1,ind2) .GT. 1.0_dp) then
            b3_dotProd(ind1,ind2) = 1.0_dp
        else if (b3_dotProd(ind1,ind2) .LT. -1.0_dp) then
            b3_dotProd(ind1,ind2) = -1.0_dp
        end if
    end do
end do
```

For what it's worth, I am compiling with `ifort`.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315306/is-if-expensive) and its various answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the intrinsic [min](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MIN.html) and [max](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MAX.html#MAX) functions for this.

As they are both elemental, you can use them on the whole array, as

```
b1_dotProd = max(-1.0_dp, min(b1_dotProd, 1.0_dp))
```

While there are [processor instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55111487/8559300) which allow `min` and `max` to be implemented without branches, it will depend on the compiler implementation of `min` and `max` as to whether or not this is actually done and if this is actually any faster, but it is at least a lot more concise.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @veryreverie is definitely correct, but there
are two things to consider.

1. A `where` statement is another sensible choice. Since it still is a conditional choice the same caveat of

> whether or not this actually avoids branches and if it's actually any faster, but it is at least a lot more concise

still applies.

One example is:

```
    pure function clamp(X) result(res)
        real, intent(in) :: X(:)
        real :: res(size(X))
        where (X < -1.0)
            res = -1.0
        else where (X > 1.0)
            res = 1.0
        else
            res = X
        end where
    end function
```

2. If you want to normalize to strictly 1 or -1, I would actually think about changing the datatype to integer. Then you can actually use `a == 1` etc. without thinking about floating point equality problems. Depending on your code I would also think about cases where the dot product gets close to zero. Of course this point only applies, if you are only interested in the sign.

```
    pure function get_sign(X) result(res)
        real, intent(in) :: X(:)
        integer :: res(size(X))
        ! Or use another appropiate choice to test for near_zero
        where (abs(X) < epsilon(X) * 10.)
            res = 0
        else where (X < 0.0)
            res = -1
        else where (X > 0.0)
            res = +1
        end where
    end function
```

Comment: As I understand the code fragment, the value is to be clamped to the interval [-1,1]. That doesn't mean "integer".

Comment: Just a nitpick, but can `where` constructs be made branchless? `min` and `max` can be implemented [using x86 instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55111487/8559300) to avoid branches altogether, but I'd be surprised if a compiler could do this for `where`.