# error: ‘asm’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, inline-assembly

I am getting the following error during compilation:

```
error: ‘asm’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 EXCHANGE( s, *(a) );
 ^
```

in a header file where the macro is invoked as follows:

```
EXCHANGE( s, *(a) );
```

and the actual defintion of the macro is as follows:

```
#define EXCHANGE(R,M) asm volatile ( "xchg   %1, %0" : "+m" (M), "+r" (R) )
```

Macro invocation and definition exists in same header file.
What's going wrong?

I am using CMAKE to build the project and CFLAGS are as follows:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Werror")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wextra")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-missing-braces")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-missing-field-initializers")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wformat=2")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wswitch-default")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wcast-align")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wpointer-arith")
#-Wno-deprecated-declarations to suppress the deprecation errors with newer version of JSON-C 
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-deprecated-declarations")
#set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wbad-function-cast")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wstrict-overflow=5")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Winline")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wundef")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wnested-externs")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-cast-qual")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wshadow")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wunreachable-code")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wfloat-equal")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wstrict-aliasing=2")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wredundant-decls")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wold-style-definition")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-unused-parameter")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c99")

#set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O0 -g3 -ggdb")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O3")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -E")
```

Comment: did you try to stop compilation after pre-processing using `-E` ?

Comment: What is -E and how can I use it? I am building my project via cmake.

Comment: Is the `asm` keyword supported by your compiler. BTW which compiler/environnement/IDE/OS are you using?

Comment: Quoting gcc's documentation: "-E Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper. The output is in the form of preprocessed source code, which is sent to the standard output."
So basically, run `gcc -E yourfile` and see if you have issues on the pre-processed code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: I am using gcc 4.8, Linux.

Comment: @Black_Zero: please make that clear in your question.

Comment: @Aif: 
I added this ' set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -E")' in CMakeLists.txt but nothing happens. The compilation stops at same point.

Comment: What are your current CFLAGS?

Comment: Please see compiler flags. [link](http://pastebin.com/U7CGNVm3)

Comment: Please add them to your post.

Comment: Change `-std=c99` to `-std=gnu99`.

Comment: @Paul R: That solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are compiling with option `-std=c99`.

This disables some non-standard GCC extensions like the `asm` feature.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-std-112 for some (not very precise) documentation.

Remove or change the line `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c99")` from your cmakefile if you need inline assembly.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: Neat, that's what I found out when I asked the compilation flag. Glad we found it.

Comment: It's possible to use `-ansi`, `-std=c99`, `-ansi -pedantic` etc flags with `__asm__` instead of `asm`. Because `__xx` is extension. And standard allows extensions. Ref.: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html#Alternate-Keywords

Answer (score 23):

**Either use `__asm__` instead of `asm` with `-std=c99`, or use `-std=gnu99`**

From the GCC docs https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

> The asm keyword is a GNU extension. When writing code that can be compiled with -ansi and the various -std options, use `__asm__` instead of asm (see Alternate Keywords).

and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html#Alternate-Keywords:

> -ansi and the various -std options disable certain keywords. This causes trouble when you want to use GNU C extensions, or a general-purpose header file that should be usable by all programs, including ISO C programs. The keywords asm, typeof and inline are not available in programs compiled with -ansi or -std (although inline can be used in a program compiled with -std=c99 or -std=c11). The ISO C99 keyword restrict is only available when -std=gnu99 (which will eventually be the default) or -std=c99 (or the equivalent -std=iso9899:1999), or an option for a later standard version, is used.
>
> The way to solve these problems is to put `__` at the beginning and end of each problematical keyword. For example, use `__asm__` instead of asm, and `__inline__` instead of inline.
>
> Other C compilers won’t accept these alternative keywords; if you want to compile with another compiler, you can define the alternate keywords as macros to replace them with the customary keywords. It looks like this:
>
> ```
> #ifndef __GNUC__
> #define __asm__ asm
> #endif
> ```
>
> -pedantic and other options cause warnings for many GNU C extensions. You can prevent such warnings within one expression by writing `__extension__` before the expression. `__extension__` has no effect aside from this.

`-std=gnu99` enables GNU extensions such as `asm`, while still keeping the language C99-like.

**C99 standard**

GCC works like this to comply with the C99 standard, which marks double underscore symbols as reserved.

From the [C99 N1256 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 7.1.3 "Reserved identifiers" 1:

> Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause, and
> optionally declares or defines identifiers listed in its associated future library directions
> subclause and identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as file
> scope identifiers.
>
> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
>   underscore are always reserved for any use.

Otherwise, if `asm` were predefined, a legal program like:

```
int asm = 0;
```

would become illegal.

**Test program**

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint32_t io = 0;
    __asm__ volatile (
        "movl %0, %%eax;"
        "inc %%eax;"
        "movl %%eax, %0;"
        : "+m" (io)
        :
        : "%eax"
    );
    assert(io == 1);
}
```

Tested on Ubuntu 17.10, GCC 7.2.

Answer (score 4):

`asm` is a gcc extension, Hence you can not used with flags like `std=c99` or `ansi`

More details at
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions