# Android ndk-build error: undefined symbol: aligned_alloc

Tags: c++, android-ndk, clang++

I am trying to build Shared Object (.so) files for the [ImageMagick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) library. However, it get stuck due to the following error while creating the *.so* file:

```
[arm64-v8a] Executable     : magick
ld: error: undefined symbol: aligned_alloc
>>> referenced by memory.c:262 (././ImageMagick-7.0.9-17/MagickCore\memory.c:262)
>>>               memory.o:(AcquireAlignedMemory) in archive ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libmagickcore-7.a
>>> referenced by memory.c:262 (././ImageMagick-7.0.9-17/MagickCore\memory.c:262)
>>>               memory.o:(AcquireVirtualMemory) in archive ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libmagickcore-7.a
>>> referenced by memory.c:262 (././ImageMagick-7.0.9-17/MagickCore\memory.c:262)
>>>               memory.o:(AcquireVirtualMemory) in archive ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libmagickcore-7.a
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/ndk/r22b/x64/build//../build/core/build-binary.mk:741: obj/local/arm64-v8a/magick] Error 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Here's a [GitHub Actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub#Scope) link where I am generating a *.so* file and for facing the error for ease of reproducing the issue.

https://github.com/malaythecool/Android-ImageMagick7/runs/2316777388?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: 1. Do you know which library provides the implementation of `aligned_alloc`? 2. Do you know if that library is getting linked to your final `.so`?

Comment: Also on what basis is `MAGICKCORE_HAVE_STDC_ALIGNED_ALLOC` defined? That's what forces the choice of the implementation in `memory.c` to choose the `aligned_alloc()` route.

Comment: aligned_alloc is actually c++ function https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc.
Moreover it's like going to fall in dark well if I change anything in code related to MAGICKCORE_HAVE_STDC_ALIGNED_ALLOC

Comment: Yes, exactly my point. That should help you figure out what might be the problem. `aligned_alloc()` wasn't there in earlier versions of C, so you need to check the library i.e. standard C library whether it ships with that implementation on your system. Also, if you've checked the warnings in your CI `././ImageMagick-7.0.9-17/MagickCore/memory.c:262:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'aligned_alloc' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`. Whatever library you're compiling against doesn't have that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) logs, it shows up:

```
././ImageMagick-7.0.9-17/MagickCore/memory.c:262:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'aligned_alloc' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Which finally ends up in the linker complaining for the missing symbol:

```
ld: error: undefined symbol: aligned_alloc
```

Try adding the flag `-std=c++1z` to your build configuration since `aligned_alloc()` was introduced in [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17).

It seems the *Application.mk* file already sets the `-std=c++17` [here](https://github.com/malaythecool/Android-ImageMagick7/blob/master/Application.mk#L43). You may try adding the following flag too:

```
APP_CONLYFLAGS += -std=c11
```

to ensure that the C standard is updated to [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) wherein `alloc_aligned()` was introduced.

Comment: Didn't solved it, however your input can be valid! Checking out more on how NDK is picking the c++ sources deeply.

Comment: @мalayмeнтa Added another suggestion for passing a flag only for the C files. See if that helps?

Comment: Ya that flag I only added after your suggestion there in Application.mk.
Let me add the new suggestion right away!

Comment: Something else popped up
 ./libfftw-3.3.8/kernel/cycle.h:559:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'asm'
https://github.com/malaythecool/Android-ImageMagick7/runs/2325770086?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: would you like to contribute there? it's open source project.

Comment: @мalayмeнтa Thanks for the invitation. I'll take a look at it once I've some time since it's setup appears to be pretty involved. For now, if your question is solved, you can accept this answer. For the `asm` error, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49830956/1851678)

Comment: I guess it's reached to half build only and aborted in between, as it;s like that point  didn't reached and build got aborted. I'll take a look again to start solving from there, and if that asm not appearing definitely yours is the answer.

Comment: I saw that `memory.c`compiled [successfully](https://github.com/malaythecool/Android-ImageMagick7/runs/2325770086?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:220) in the last run. See if the `asm`change works too. Adding `-std=gnu99` should help.

Comment: You're right, I just checked it passed memory.c!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is facing this issue, bump up the `minSdkVersion` to `28` in your *build.gradle* file.

The Android NDK seems to define these functions based on `minSdkVersion`, even when you have `-std=c11` in your CFLAGS.

File *~/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h*:

```
#if ANDROID_API >= 28
void* aligned_alloc(size_t alignment, size_t __size) __INTRODUCED_IN(28);
#endif /* __ANDROID_API >= 28 */
```