# My assembly function push data twice

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

so I've been debugging this and made a function to send a packet to the server

here is the function

```
Naked void CB::Send_To_Server(CHARARRAY Buffer, int Length)
{
    __asm
    {    
            PUSH ESI
            LEA EAX, Length
            MOVZX ECX, DWORD PTR DS : [Buffer]
            PUSH ECX
            PUSH EAX
            MOV ECX, NetworkClass
            CALL Send_Packet_Original_Address
            POP ESI
            RET

    }
}
```

the problem here is first when I debug my application it shows that
the function has 3 arguments instead of 2 (Buffer,Length,Length) and
when I use it it actually pushes the length twice the first time is the
correct length the second time it's some weird negative long number like
-29470056 <---- Not rly a value that showed to me just an example

so as you might see I am rly bad with both c++ and asm so if anyone has an
idea on how to fix this or maybe it's normal I'd rly appreciate your help :)

Comment: You didn't provide enough information but I would at least do the following things 1) use `mov eax, [length]` not `lea` 2) use `push [Buffer]` not `movzx`+`push` 3) delete the `ret`. Also no idea why you need inline asm for this, it looks like you are just chaining to a different method. `push esi`/`pop esi` seems unnecessary too since that doesn't get modified.

Comment: @Jester I tried it it still pushed the length twice and esi is a pointer which I enter and I need it to return (I think) also I made it that way so I mirrored the same function as the game so it doesn't crash (as I said I don't know much about asm) and what more information do you need?

Comment: I suggest writing a similar function in C++ and have the compiler print out the assembly language.  Next compare to your implementation of the function.

Comment: Why are you doing this in asm in the first place?  [MSVC inline asm is not very good](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323445/what-is-the-difference-between-asm-and-asm/35959859#35959859), and you don't appear to be doing anything that a compiler couldn't easily generate.  (and do a better job than that: e.g. you have a useless(?) save/restore of a register you never touch (`esi`).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to refer to arguments by name `EBP` must be set to the value of `ESP` on entry to the function, if the function is not declared as naked this is done automatically.