# Difference between asm and __asm__ in kernel code

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, inline

I was looking how memory barriers are used in the kernel (Linux kernel v4.19-rc5). I don't understand the difference between `asm`asm and `__asm__`. For example, consider barrier function:

```
static inline void barrier(void)
{
    asm volatile("" : : : "memory");
}
```

This function uses `asm` and `volatile` keywords and it is a software barrier. On the other hand, consider a hardware barrier like this one:

```
#define mb()    __asm__ __volatile__("mb": : :"memory")
```

This time, the keywords `__asm__` and `__volatile__` were used. What is the difference between them? I understand from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323445/what-is-the-difference-between-asm-asm-and-asm) post that the difference comes from the compiler but I don't understand why both versions (`__asm__` and `asm`) were used in the same source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read @Ciro's answer on that question? [What is the difference between 'asm', '__asm' and '__asm__'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323445/what-is-the-difference-between-asm-asm-and-asm/49830990#49830990).

It explains that `asm` and `__asm__` are the same except that `gcc -std=c99` disables `asm`, leaving only `__asm__`.

`asm` is a convenience name for `__asm__`, and is available in GNU C mode, which is the default (`-std=gnu99` / `-std=gnu11` or whatever).

---

There is exactly zero difference in behaviour.  Some contributors to Linux preferred `__asm__`, while others used `asm`.  Linux is compiled with `-std=gnu99` or `gnu11`, because it *definitely* depends on GNU extensions to C.

I don't think either of those occurrences were in header that could be included elsewhere, outside of Linux.  `__asm__` isn't *wrong* in GNU C code.  But if you need code to work even when compiled with `-std=c11`, then `asm` is wrong.

---

Only MSVC's `__asm` keyword is different, and uses `__asm { insn; insn; }` and isn't supported by mainline gcc.  (Apple's gcc for older OS X that uses an LLVM back-end supports `-fasm-blocks`, like current Clang.)

Comment: Actually it's oDisPo's answer to the question you linked that more correctly answers this question. The choice of `asm` versus `__asm__` isn't (or shouldn't be) by preference.

Comment: @RossRidge: That's kind of what I was trying to say, that `asm` is a convenience name for `__asm__`, and is available in GNU C mode.  But even though Linux is definitely dependent on GNU C, some contributors still preferred `__asm__` I guess.  Or maybe it was going into headers that could be included elsewhere?  `__asm__` isn't *wrong* in GNU C code.

Comment: The `__asm__` keyword should be used in `.h` files because `.c` files may use macros to redefine `asm` to mean something else.  The `asm` keyword should be used in `.c` files because it's shorter and its safe to use because `.h` files shouldn't redefine it to mean something else.