# The -masm=intel flag is not working for running assembly language in gcc compiler with Intel syntax

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I am trying to use inline assembler __asm in my C program with Intel syntax as opposed to AT&T syntax. I am compiling with `gcc -S -masm=intel test.c`
but it is giving error. Below is my test.c file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//using namespace std;
int AsmCode(int num,int power) {
    __asm {
        mov eax, num;
        mov ecx, power;
        shl eax, cl;
    };
}
int main()
{
    printf("eax value is %d\n",AsmCode(2,3));

    //getchar();
    return 0;



}
```

Expected result was eax value is 16, but errors are occurring like unknown type name 'mov',unknown type name 'shl' etc.

Edit:
I have updated the code as:

```
int AsmCode(int num,int power) {
    __asm__ (
        "movl eax, num;"
        "mov ecx, power;"
        "shl eax, cl;"
    );
}
int main()
{
    printf("eax value is %d\n",AsmCode(2,3));
    return 0;
}
```

And compiled this code with `gcc -S -masm=intel test.c`. This resulted in **NO OUTPUT**, whereas it should produce output as `eax value is 16`.

When compiled with `gcc test.c` it produced the errors:

```
Error: too many memory references for 'mov'
Error: too many memory references for 'shl'
```

Please help..

Comment: Please copy-paste the error messages, instead of paraphrasing them.

Comment: Always read the first error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important error is the first one:

```
main.cpp:4:11: error: expected '(' before '{' token
     __asm {
           ^
           (
```

You're using the wrong syntax for GCC. You've used Microsoft Visual Studio syntax. So, your GCC doesn't know that you're trying to give it assembly instructions.

Instead of `__asm { ... }`, it should be `__asm__ ( "..." )`.

Like this:

```
int AsmCode(int num,int power) {
    __asm__ (
        "mov eax, num;"
        "mov ecx, power;"
        "shl eax, cl;"
    );
}
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323445/560648).

Note that there are further issues with your ASM that you should ask about separately.

Comment: You can't just use `num`, `power`, etc. in GCC syntax without declaring them as inputs. And you'd probably want to specify clobbers.

Comment: There are certainly other issues. I'll let the OP raise a ASM question if they can't figure that bit out.

Comment: Alright. Just seems to be confusing to provide not working code as an example (without indication that it's not supposed to work) to already struggling OP.

Comment: @DanM. Perhaps but I'm only keen to answer the C++ question that was asked, particularly as I don't know ASM.

Comment: @DanM. I know we can't use directly the variable names in GCC syntax without declaring them, because they use AT&T syntax. But ```masm= intel``` should make them compatible to run with GCC compiler as they were with Visual studio compiler

Comment: @AbhilashBarigidad no. You are confusing intel vs at&t syntax with inline assembly compiler extension (and its "syntax"). They have little to do with each over. You can use intel syntax for asm in GCC (i.e. implicit types, no $ before constants, different argument order and etc.), but you still need to conform to `__asm__` [syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Comment: @DanM. I have updated the code as requested, please look into it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Have updated code, please look into it.

Comment: @AbhilashBarigidad Like I said, you have errors unrelated to your original question - please ask them in a new question. I do not know ASM so will not be able to help with that one.