# Passing integer to x86 ASM in C++

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

I am trying to do some script hooking in C++, and have setup a simple test function for this case.

```
   void __declspec(naked) testFunct()
{
    int myInt;
    myInt = 2000;
    __asm{
        mov eax, myInt
        jmp [jmp_back_address]
    }
}
```

when using this to pass in the integer, the function fails when it is called and the project crashes. However, when using this instead, without an integer value, it successfully passes through.

```
   void __declspec(naked) testFunct()
{
    __asm{
        mov eax, 2000
        jmp [jmp_back_address]
    }
}
```

How can I successfully pass the integer?

Comment: What does the assembly generated by the first version look like?

Comment: Write the function in C++.  Tell the compiler to print the assembly language.  Review the assembly language for argument passing.  Done.

Comment: `mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-8],7D0
mov eax,dword ptr ss:[ebp-8]
jmp dword ptr ds:[<unsigned long jmp_back_address>]`

Comment: What does the code whose address is stored in `jmp_back_address` do?  Please provide  a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution for my situation was to simply do everything within the ourFunct() through ASM instead, as mixing both C++ and ASM for passing variables was creating buggy assembly code. Example with a function call that works:

```
int CalculateTotalScore()
{
    return (int)*Game::current_speed_score;
}

DWORD jmpBackAddress;
void __declspec(naked) ourFunct()
{
    __asm{
        call CalculateTotalScore
        jmp [jmpBackAddress]
    }
}
```

Comment: So probably like in GNU C, `naked` functions can only use `asm{}` blocks, not any plain C++ code.

Comment: Correct, even though it doesn't throw any warnings, and will still compile, the x86 code it compiles will not take into account the handwritten asm code.

Comment: Actually the problem is that compiler-generated code doesn't take into account that it's in a naked function, and does things like assume EBP is set up as a frame pointer without emitting code to do that.  https://godbolt.org/z/5n41KK5zz.  The hand-written asm itself isn't the problem.  But yeah, it's odd that MSVC at least doesn't even warn about that non-asm code in a `naked` function.

Answer (score -1):

The assembler doesn't know what "myInt" means. Most compilers support inline assembly with the possibility to pass values. For instance, with GCC, you may try to define a macro like

```
#define MY_ASM_MACRO(myInt) ({ asm volatile("mov eax,%0\n\t \
          jmp [jmp_back_address]" : : "r"(myInt) : ); })
```

And use it like

```
void __declspec(naked) testFunct()
{
   int myInt;
   myInt = 2000;
   MY_ASM_MACRO(myInt)
}
```

Comment: MSVC inline asm is completely different; it *does* use C var names inside asm *blocks*.  (Like `clang -fasm-blocks`).  That and `__declspec` are how we can tell this is Visual C++, not GNU C++ syntax.  [What is the difference between 'asm', '\_\_asm' and '\_\_asm\_\_'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35959859)

Comment: Also, your macro isn't safe; you need a `__builtin_unreachable();` after the asm statement, because you unconditionally jump out of it.  Also, just ask for `myInt` in EAX in the first place with `"a"(myInt)`.  It's silly to make the compiler materialize the value in a different register, and not even let it use an immediate.

Comment: Or actually this is an `__attribute__((naked))` function, so `__builtin_unreachable()` isn't needed, but also it's not supported to use GNU C Extended Asm.  Only Basic Asm is supported in naked functions in GNU C.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#index-naked-function-attribute_002c-x86