# arm inline assembly - store C variable in arm register

Tags: c, assembly, arm

Trying to save a variable in an arm register using inline assembly.

```
    unsigned int lma_offset = 0x1234; // typically calculated, hardcoded for example

    __asm volatile ("MOV R10, %[input]"
        : [input] "=r" (lma_offset)
      );
```

This *changes* lma_offset to 0xd100 in my case, instead of setting the register. What am I doing wrong?

PS: when I declare lma_offset as `const` it gives a compiler error because lma_offset is used as output. So obviously something is wrong, still I cant find the correct syntax for this.

Comment: Outputs are listed after the first colon. Inputs are listed after another colon. Do not use `=`; that is for output operands. Given that you report `lma_offset` changes as a result of this, I presume you are using an assembler with AT&T syntax (source on left, destination on right). Also, `__asm` is suspicious; I would expect either `__asm__` or `asm`. You could try `__asm__ volatile("MOV %[input], R10" : : [input] "r" (lma_offset));`. However, while this might copy `lma_offset` to `R10`, it will not keep it there. The compiler is free to use R10 for other purposes…

Comment: … You could add more information to the `__asm__` to tell the compiler you are putting something in R10, but there is no way in an `__asm__` construct to tell the compiler to keep it there and not to use R10 for any other purpose. You can declare a register variable that is assigned to R10, but what is the point? Why do you want something in R10, and for how long?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  The moment your ASM statement ends, the compiler is free to overwrite r10 with whatever it wants.  Also, as you have not declared `r10` to be clobbered, it may expect R10 to keep its previous value.  So overall, it's not really clear what effect you expect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil AT&T syntax is a thing for x86, not ARM.  There is no AT&T syntax for ARM.  What happens is that as `lma_offset` is listed as an output operand, the compiler picks a random register and assumes its contents will hold the variable `lma_offset` after the inline assembly is done.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am using r10 to pass a value between my bootloader and the actual app.

Comment: @fuz could you tell me how to list `lma_offset` as a input instead?

Comment: @bas You will not be able to do it this way.  Instead, you have to do the parameter passing and the function call in a single `asm` statement.  As for passing it as an input, do what Eric Postpischil says.  You can also use register variables to tell the compiler to directly put `lma_offset` into `r10` in your asm statement so you don't have to emit a possibly useless `mov`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, right, if I had read your comment better I would have found this out a bit sooner... adding another `:` and removing the `=` indeed does the trick.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ps, `__asm` and `__asm__` seem to be identical (some fuzz about namespace) according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323445/what-is-the-difference-between-asm-asm-and-asm. the nxp sdk uses `__asm` everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, according to Erics comment

```
const unsigned int lma_offset = 0x10000;

__asm__ volatile ("MOV R10, %[input]"
    : // no C variable outputs
    : [input] "r" (lma_offset)
    : "R10"      // tell the compiler R10 is modified
      );
```

using double `:` and replacing the "=r" with "r" indeed solves the problem.

It would also be possible to ask the compiler to have that constant already in R10 for an asm statement, by using a register local variable to force the `"r"` input to pick `r10`.  (Then we can omit the redundant `mov r10, r10`).

```
 register unsigned r10 __asm__("r10") = lma_offset;  // picks r10 for "r" constraints, no other *guaranteed* effects
 __asm__ volatile ("@ inline asm went here"  // empty template, actually just a comment you can see if looking at the compiler's asm output
   : // no C variable outputs
   : [input] "r" (lma_offset)
   : // no clobbers needed
 );
```

---

When writing a register to some output C variable it would result in

```
unsigned int lma_offset = 0x0;

__asm__ volatile ("MOV %[output], R11"
    : [output] "=r" (lma_offset)
    // no clobbers needed; reading a register doesn't step on the compiler's toes
      );
```