# Why does inline asm LEA on a class member variable compile to a constant zero in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

When I compile a C++ program that uses assembly (using Visual Studio 2022), some of the assembly code appears to be adjusted or at least optimized away (but I have optimizations disabled).

Does anyone know what's going on and how I can make it not do this?

The purpose behind this code (at least the non-summarized version) is to create a wrapper class for another class defined in a DLL that I do not have the source for. Essentially, I am calling the constructor of the DLL class which requires ECX to be an address in the stack that points to 0 (an empty pointer).

**SampleClass.h**

```
class SampleClass
{
public:
    SampleClass();

private:
    uintptr_t value1;
};
```

**SampleClass.cpp**

```
SampleClass::SampleClass() : 
    value1(0)
{
    __asm {
        // When I compile this converts to LEA ECX, 0...
        // I want it to hold the value for the address of value1.
        LEA ECX, DWORD PTR SS : [value1]
    }
}
```

If I adjust the function to this, it doesn't remove/change the code... but crashes at the end of the function saying that the stack data around value2 is corrupt.

```
SampleClass::SampleClass() : 
    value1(0)
{
    uintptr_t value2;

    __asm {
        LEA ECX, DWORD PTR SS : [value2]
    }

    value1 = value2;
    // Crashes here...
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use assembly? If not in general you probably won't write faster code than your compiler does : [CppCon 2017: Matt Godbolt “What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4). And you could argue that the compiler was right deducing that value1 always will be 0, I am curious what would happen if you made value1 `volatile`

Comment: @harold I'm trying to make a wrapper object for an object that I do not have the source for. In this case I'm trying to create the object and the value of ECX should be a stack address with a value of 0 (since the object doesn't exist yet).

Comment: Ok then my reply doesn't make much sense, it would have helped if in your question you would first explain what you wanted to do, and then show your "how". But I think this approach is not going to work, to get a valid instance (of the object you don't have the source for) you should call its constructor not just place some data in registers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that. @PepijnKramer.. also making it volatile changed it to DWORD PTR DS:[0] (instead of DWORD PTR SS : [address that should not be 0].)

Comment: What's the point of setting ECX inside an `_asm{}` block without doing anything with that value?  MSVC's simplistic inline asm syntax doesn't have any way to tell the compiler about outputs in registers, so you have to `mov` to a C++ variable if you want it to do anything.

Comment: Also, crashes how, on what instruction when you disassemble in the debugger (so you also see compiler-generated asm)?  Your code looks perfectly safe; like I said the inline asm does nothing.  (Unless you're compiling with `thiscall` or `fastcall`, because [MSVC doesn't support inline asm for functions with register args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323445/what-is-the-difference-between-asm-asm-and-asm#comment59576185_35959859) / https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a8ss06.aspx.  And overwriting ECX could be destroying its copy of `this` because MSVC is really dumb.)

Comment: Just thinking : Maybe in the end you're better of reverse engineering the class declaration of the class (you don't have the source for) and let the compiler do all the work.

Comment: @PeterCordes this was just a small version of the code, the real code calls the constructor of a class in a different DLL once the value of ECX is assigned to an address of a null pointer. I updated my original post to describe this.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Unfortunately I don't think I'm skilled enough to do something like that yet...

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/8W1GjscEs shows that `lea reg, varname` works for actual local vars, including `this`.  Also that by default it's using `thiscall`, since we can see it storing ECX to the stack, which means we're in undefined-behaviour territory.  Also, it's not constant-propagation of the *value* `value1(0)`, since changing that to `value1(456)` still results in an LEA of address `0`.  (@PepijnKramer).

Comment: What do you want to do with ECX that you can't do with `void *ptr = &value1;`?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Wouldn't you want the *value* of `this` in a register, like `mov ecx, this`, if you want to add `offsetof(SampleClass, value1)` to it to get `&(this->value1)`?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Yes, exactly.  `this` is a variable of type `SampleClass*`, and you want that 4-byte pointer value in a register.  Since the compiler spilled it from ECX to the stack (and won't accept `__cdecl` to take it on the stack in the first place), we need a load to get `this` instead of `&this`.

Comment: If you want to call a function with a specific value in `ecx`, better would be to declare a `__fastcall` function. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bfxjr7nPb

Comment: You would have to get the `this` address into a register with `mov` and then you would have to reference the `value1` member. Something like this might work `MOV ECX, this` `LEA ECX, [ecx].value1` . ECX would then contain the address of `this->value1`

Comment: As for the other part of your question, `LEA ECX, DWORD PTR SS : [value1]` moves the offset of `value1` within the class. In your case the offset is 0. If you were to add other members before `value1` in `SampleClass` you'd see the offset change. You need to load the address of the `this`  and then from there compute the offset of the member `value1` to get the address of `this->value` at runtime as I suggested. I'm not sure what you are doing with ECX after you get it, but I'm really answering the question in the title of your question.

Comment: Thank you everyone, @MichaelPetch that was the solution!